# get specific record from an active record relation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following data in database for table customer

```
id   customer_address     code       created_at            updated_at
1                         abc_1    2017-11-21 02:58:04  2017-11-21 02:58:04
2    122 st. CA           abc_1    2017-11-24 14:26:02  2017-11-24 14:26:02
3    224 st. CA           abc_1    2017-11-28 14:26:02  2017-11-28 14:26:02
```

Customer address for first record id=1 is blank. Code is same for each customer. For code input param i want to return record which has most updated address so in this case record id=3.
I have following activerecord relation available in @address

```
#<ActiveRecord: : Relation[
  #<Address id: 1,
  customer_address: “”,
  code: “abc_1”,
  created_at: "2017-11-21 02:58:04",
  updated_at: "2017-11-21 02:58:04">,
  #<Address id: 2,
  customer_address: “123 st.CA”,
  code: “abc_1”,
  created_at: "2017-11-24 14:26:02",
  updated_at: "2017-11-24 14:26:02">,
  #<Address id: 3,
  customer_address: “224 st.CA”,
  code: “abc_1”,
  created_at: "2017-11-28 14:26:02",
  updated_at: "2017-11-28 14:26:02">,
]>
```

I tried following

```
@address = @address.select { |h| h[:customer_address] != '' } if @address.any? { |h| h[:customer_address] == '' }
@address = [@address.max_by { |h| h[:created_at] }]
```

is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `@address.where(customer_address: nil).order("updated_at ASC").last`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Address
  .where(code: "abc_1")
  .where.not(customer_address: ['', nil])
  .order(:updated_at)
  .last
```

This does not necessarily guarantee what you are asking, since you don't actually *store* "when was the address last updated"; you only store when the *record* was last updated.

So this could also, for example, be when the `code` changed. However, this is the best you can do given the current data model.

This approach is better than your original, since the entire query is performed in a single SQL statement and no additional records are loaded into memory.